# Find the value of $2xy$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

> If  $13x+17y=643$ ,$\{x,y\}\in \mathbb{N}$, then what is the value of two times the product of 
>   $x$ and $y$ ?

**Options**

$a.)\ 744\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
b.)\ 844\\
\color{green}{c.)\ 924}\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
d.)\ 884\\$

I tried,

$13x+17y \pmod{13}\equiv 0\\
\implies 2y  \pmod{13}\equiv 3 \\
\implies y=8
\implies y=8, x=39$

$2xy=624$

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: have you solved the equation? i have found $(x,y)=(5,34),(22,21),(39,8))$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard:Ok i see my fault , but what could I have done in case the solution pairs would have been more than $6$ , then it would be cumbersome to try and see each case for me.

Answer (score 4):

When applying mod $13$, the equation $13x+17y=643$ becomes
$$4y\equiv 6\pmod{13}$$
or
$$40y\equiv 60\pmod {13}$$
that is, $y\equiv 8\pmod {13}$.

Now, to find $x$, apply mod $17$:

$$13x\equiv 14\pmod{17}$$
or
$$4\cdot 13x\equiv 56\pmod {17}$$
thus, $x\equiv 5\pmod{17}$.

Now we are to find the concrete values of $x$ and $y$:
$$13(17u+5)+17(13v+8)=643$$
which yields
$$221(u+v)+201=643$$
therefore, $u+v=2$. Since $u$ and $v$ must not be negative, we have three possibilities:

- $u=2$, $v=0$. Then $x=39$, $y=8$, so $2xy=624$.
- $u=v=1$. Then $x=22$, $y=21$. Then $2xy=924$.
- $u=0$, $v=2$. Then $x=5$, $y=34$. Then $2xy=340$.

Answer (score 0):

$13x+17y=643=13\cdot50-7=13\cdot50-7(13\cdot4-17\cdot3)$

$\iff13(x-22)=17(21-y)\implies \dfrac{17(21-y)}{13}=x-22$ which is an integer

$\implies13|17(21-y),\implies13|(21-y)$ as $(13,17)=1$

$\implies21-y=13m\iff  y=21-13m$

and  consequently, $x=22+17m$ where $m$ is an integer

We need $21-13m=y>0\iff13m <21\implies m\le0$ as $m$ is an integer

and $22+17m=x>0\iff17m>-22\implies m\ge-1$  as $m$ is an integer

$\implies-1\le m\le0$

Can you take it home from here?